# setTimeout not work with $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("ul > li").mouseenter(function(){
                setTimeout(function () {
                     $(this).find(".ul2").show();
                 }, 2000);
            });
            $("ul > li").mouseleave(function(){
                $(this).find(".ul2").hide();
            });
        });
```

```css
.ul1{
                list-style: none;
                position: absolute;
            }
            .ul1 > li{
                float: left;
                margin-left: 40px;
            }
            .ul2{
                display: none;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            .ul2 li{
                display: block;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul1">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <ul class="ul2">
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Home</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">about</a>
            <ul class="ul2">
                <li>about</li>
                <li>about</li>
                <li>about</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">other</a>
            <ul class="ul2">
                <li>other</li>
                <li>other</li>
                <li>other</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I'm use setTimeout it not work with $(this)...
without using of setTimeout it work...
so tell me what wrong here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` inside of a function refers to that function, not the "outer" function's `this`.

```
setTimeout(function () { // you have a new this now
    $(this).find(".ul2").show();
}, /* you have the old this now */ 2000);
```

You need to either get a reference to `this` outside of the function:

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function () {
    $(that).find(".ul2").show();
}, 2000);
```

or bind a different `this` to the function:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(this).find(".ul2").show();
}.bind(this), 2000);
```